# Avoiding set up policy permissions to each ECR repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to set up cross-account access to ECR. What I'd like is to allow one AWS account to access the ECR in a different AWS account. The point is that it is needed to set up a policy permission under each repository. I don't like honestly this approach because for each new repository created under the ECR, I need to set up a policy. Do you have a better strategy to allow one account to automatically access all the repos in a ECR in a different AWS account?

Comment: Well if you use any sort of IaC tool like terraform or the AWS native cloudformation, you can achieve automated setting up policy...

Comment: not really what I'm looking for. I know that strategy you mentioned. I mean if it is REALLY mandatory to set up policy for each repository

Comment: Yes it is REALLY mandatory. On AWS you always need to explicitly grant permissions especially for this kind of cross account access.